# Python AJAX not Posting to the Database

Tags: javascript, python, ajax

So, I am trying to get my Post updated to the database without having to refresh using AJAX function but instead of the Post being updated in the database it returns a

> http://127.0.0.1:5000/?description=New+to+do+statement+4
> in the URL without Posting to the database. Below is my HTML and JavaScript code

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Todo App</title>
        <style>
        .hidden{
            display:none;
        }</style>
    </head>
    <body>

        <form id="form">
            <input type="text" name="description" id="">
            <input type="submit" value="Create">
        </form>

        <div id="error" class="hidden">Something went wrong</div>
        <ul>
            {% for d in data %}
                <li>{{d.description}}</li>
            {% endfor %}    
        </ul>

        <script>
            document.getElementById('form').onsubmit = function (e) {
                e.preventDefault():
                fetch('/todo/create', {
                    method: 'POST',
                    body: JSON.stringify({
                        'description': document.getElementById('description').value
                    }),
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
                    }
                })
                .then(function(response) {
                    return response.json();
                })
                .then(function(jsonResponse){
                    console.log(jsonresponse);
                    const liItem= document.createElement('LI');
                    liItem.innerHTML = jsonResponse['description'];
                    document.getElementById('todo').appendChild(liItem);
                    document.getElementById('error').className='hidden';
                })

                .catch(function(){
                    document.getElementById('error').className = '';
                })
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Below is my Python code

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for, jsonify
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'postgresql://postgres:MassRay12@localhost:5432/todoapp'
# app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class Todo(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'todo'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    description = db.Column(db.String(), nullable=False)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'<Todo {self.id} {self.description}>'

db.create_all()

@app.route('/todo/create', methods=['POST'])
def create_todo():
    description = request.get_json()['description']
    todo = Todo(description=description)
    db.session.add(todo)
    db.session.commit()
    return jsonify({
        'description': todo.description
    })

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html', data = Todo.query.all())
```

Please help, i have been stuck on this for a while.

Comment: You have a syntax error after `e.preventDefault()`:

Comment: But if I remove the `:` in `e.preventDefault():` It would not submit , what should I now write theere @Musa

Comment: Check your developer console for errors.

Comment: Solved it, I just had to change the : then put ;